# How can I center a modal div in the middle of the screen?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
   <div class="block-border" style="width: 900px; height: 450px;">
   xxx
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying this script:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var modal_width = modal.width;
var modal_height = modal.height;
var window_width = window.width;
var window_height = window.height;
modal.style.left = window_width / 2 - modal_width / 2;
modal.style.top = window_height / 2 - modal_height / 2;
```

When I check the modal variable it looks correct. However the modal_width and modal_height variables show undefined. I tried moving the width and height style to the first div but I still can't find the width and height.

Comment: You don't want to use jQueryUI, or don't want to use jQuery at all? And what is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
function setmodal()
{
  var modal_width = $('.modal').width(),
  window_width = window.width;
  $('.modal').css('left', window_width/2 - modal_width/2);  
}
window.onresize = function(){
    setmodal();
}
$(function(){
 setmodal();
});
```

Javascript :

```
function setmodal()
{
  var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0],
  modal_width = modal.width,
  window_width = window.width;
  modal.style.left = window_width/2 - modal_width/2;    
}
window.onresize = function(){
    setmodal();
}
```

Only drawback is support in IE 8 and <